# Describe in English the pattern in the following regular expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-expressions

Describe (in English phrases) the languages associated with the following regular expression.
it says to be as simple as possible

```
#1 (x (yyy + x)*)*
#2 (c (cc)*d(dd)*)*
```

for number 1 I got all words in which when y is in the word it can only appear in blocks that are divisible by 3(0,3,6,9, etc.)

the second question I can not see any type of pattern.

I would like to know if the first one is correct, and if what pattern is on the second one?

Thanks